# Settings schema 'org.gnome.desktop.privacy' does not contain a key named 'privacy-screen'

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell-extension

I'm trying to create a GNOME extension with [this doc](https://gjs.guide/extensions/development/creating.html#enabling-the-extension) but when I type `dbus-run-session -- gnome-shell --nested --wayland` it says `(gnome-shell:-----): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: : Settings schema 'org.gnome.desktop.privacy' does not contain a key named 'privacy-screen'`. How do i resolve this problem? I am very new to all this GNOME stuff but would love to be able to create an extension, thank u!